# Modify keys of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object of objects and I want to change the keys of the objects

```
"opening_hours": {
  "0": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "1": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "2": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "3": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "4": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "5": {
    "is_open": false
  },
  "6": {
    "is_open": false
  }
}
```

like:"0" I want it to be 'Monday', Is this possible in Javascript?

Expected Output is :

```
{
  "monday": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "wednesday": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "thursday": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "friday": {
    "close": "17:00:00",
    "is_open": true,
    "open": "09:00:00"
  },
  "saturday": {
    "is_open": false
  },
  "sunday": {
    "is_open": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @rasika your question has been marked Flag by moderator. If you need solution you can contact me !

Comment: @Rishab What do you mean by *"marked Flag by moderator"*?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `days` array which has index of an item same as the day (Eg: `0` for `monday` and so on). Loop through the keys of `opening_hours` object and add new key-value pairs to the output like this:

```js
const days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"],
    opening_hours = {"0":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"1":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"2":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"3":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"4":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"5":{is_open:false},"6":{is_open:false}},
    output = {};

for(const key in opening_hours)
  output[days[key]] = opening_hours[key];
  
console.log(output)
```

You could also [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and update the number to `days[number]` to get the string. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create a new object.

```js
const days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"],
    opening_hours={"0":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"1":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"2":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"3":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"4":{close:"17:00:00",is_open:true,open:"09:00:00"},"5":{is_open:false},"6":{is_open:false}},
    updatedEntries = Object.entries(opening_hours).map(([k, v]) => [days[k], v]),
    output = Object.fromEntries(updatedEntries);

console.log(output)
```